# justify-content issues, align is working but justify not?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to center items vertically with justify-content while using the flex-column property applied.  align-items is working as it should but the content is not responding to the Y axis.  I have align-items commented out, I dont want to center X axis, just the Y axis.

```css
.img1-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  /* align-items: center; */
  height: 100%;
}

.web-dev {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 60px;
}

.john-sass {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 48px;
  margin-left: 38.5%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="img1">
  <div class="container img1-container d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
    <h1 class="into-text web-dev"> Front-End Web Developer</h1>
    <h4 class="into-text john-sass">John Sasser</h4>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: remove  margin-left: 38.5%;

Comment: I had the issue before that addition, I tried again without it and same issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It was the height on the img1-container.....
Im guessing that adding the height property messes with the code behind the flexbox.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do some div management to get this right , like this,

```css
.img1 {
  display: table;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.content{
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
    <div class="img1">
        <div class="container img1-container d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
          <div class="content">
            <h1 class="into-text web-dev"> Front-End Web Developer</h1>
            <h4 class="into-text john-sass">John Sasser</h4>
         </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

just add `justify-content: space-between;` to your .img1-container class instead of justify-content: center;

```css
  * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .img1-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: gray;
    padding: 30px 0px;
  }

  .web-dev {
   font-size: 60px;
 }

 .john-sass {
   font-size: 48px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="img1">
    <div class="container img1-container d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
      <h1 class="into-text web-dev"> Front-End Web Developer</h1>
      <h4 class="into-text john-sass">John Sasser</h4>

    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Huh, i tried that as well.  It must be something else locally that is causing the issue.  Ill keep hunting and respond if/when i finally find it ha

Answer (score 1):

It's just working fine with the  `align-items: center;` You might not be able to notice it, 
Here's the working example. Tell me if I have missed something
https://codepen.io/shivam1100/pen/yLymveb?editors=1100

Comment: huh, it must be something else locally.

Answer (score 0):

I keep a 100% width and 100% view height

```js
.img1{
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
}

.img1-container{
  height:100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  align-items:center;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="img1">
  <div class="container img1-container">
    <h1 class="into-text web-dev">Front-End Web Developer</h1>
    <h4 class="into-text john-sass">John Sasser</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I was using height: 100%; instead of vh in the .img1-container {}